# Background picture has margin top,left,right how to remove it

Tags: html, css

Background picture has margin top,left and right, trued to remove it with position absolute and relative, didn't worked what can true else to remove them.

HTML

```
<header class="banner"></header>
```

Css

```
banner {
  background-image: url(../images/banner.jpg);
  min-height: 750px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center top; }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be initial margin of HTML page. Remove it through CSS:

```
body{margin:0}
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS

```
body {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```

You can use too reset.css;

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 1):

This is being added by either the `body` or the `header`. Add the following to the CSS stylesheet:

`body {
    margin: 0;
}`

Or, the same thing with the `body` replaced with `header`.